# How check if customer system is S/4 HANA Essentials (Multi Tenant)

Tags: abap, s4hana

Is it possible to determine via code if the current system is S/4HANA Cloud Essentials?

I have a requirement in which I must only enable a field if it is not a S/4HANA Cloud Essentials system.

I have found this question: [How to programmatically tell if system is R/3 or S/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583610/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-system-is-r-3-or-s-4) but with class `cl_cos_utilities` I can only check if the system is S/4HANA Cloud.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by enabling the field you mean In-App Extensibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my knowledge is correct we can't make ABAP development in S/4HANA Cloud Essentials. If you want to check it manualy, may be you can check system full domain name (SAPLOCALHOSTFULL) in `RZ11` t-code. I am not sure but we can see `sap` domain in SAPLOCALHOSTFULL.